# Saving blank form as PDF

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible to create a PDF version of a blank form? I know you can convert entries to PDF docs, but would like to have a blank version of the form to print and present in a meeting.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

You can create a PDF of your Cognito Form in two different ways.

The first would be to create a new entry on the Entries page, and before filling anything out select the print option from the in browser tool bar just above your Cognito Form. You can then select to 'print to pdf' rather then printing to paper.

[image]

The second would be to select the 'Create Document' option also in the in browser tool bar. This could also be done from the Entries page while creating a new entry, so that its blank. If you have not yet edited your default documents, you will want to select the second option. The will have 'form controls' enabled and will show the field areas for your unfilled form in the PDF.

[image]